# Android loading many images into gridview

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap

In one section of my app , I m showing images to 1024+ websites inside a gridview. When the images are not present on the devices they are downloaded with an async task and the image is saved in the data folder. The grid view has a section indexer, adapter and fast scroll associated with it.

However I have noticed that the app becomes really slow when I try to fast scroll to different positions in the app. A solution [`\[here\]\[1\]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) hints implementing a hashmap to store images. The total size of the images I have are around .3mb . Will storing the bitmap in the map help speed up the app ?

Comment: Search for Picasso, this will solve all your prob

Comment: you need to use [link](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading).